# How can I echo the User role using Kohana 2 Auth

Tags: php, kohana

Just trying to echo the role array of the current user to the screen using Kohana 2 and the Auth module.

Comment: I want to be able to obtain the role from the Auth->instance->get_User()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have the models setup correctly..

```
$user_id = Auth::instance()->get_user()->id;
$roles = ORM::factory('user', $user_id)->roles;

foreach ($roles as $role)....etc.
```

Comment: I think this other Wes has it.

Comment: Hah, it's a battle of the Wes' at my office, we have 3 Wes devs out of 8!

Comment: Wow. Must be a popular profession for guys named Wes. I don't even know anyone else named Wes. Anyway, Cheers!